# Nested \discretionary-ies in (Xe)LaTex resulting an error

Tags: xetex, errors, discretionary

I want to set an automatic hyphenation for the Armenian word **յանդգնել** in XeLaTeX with \discretionary. The problem is, that there are four consonants in a row, and the Armenian language has very strange (for English speakers) rules about hyphenating such words. That word can hyphenated in two ways: **յան֊դ*ը*գնել** and **յանդ*ը*գ֊նել**, in both of them the letter **ը** reappears where it sounds. This can be correctly achieved with

`յան\h{֊}{դըգ}{դ\h{ըգ֊}{}{գ}}նել`,

where I've defined `\h` as

`\newcommand{\h}[3]{\discretionary{#1}{#2}{#3}}`,

but there are nested `\h`-s here, so it gives an error

`Improper discretionary list. ... յան\h{֊}{դըգ}{դ\h{ըգ֊}{}{գ}}`

and the compiler (XeLaTex) just removes the second `\h` where it is needed.

I've found nothing about this topic in the Internet, and, unfortunately, there is no automatic hyphenation package for the Armenian language. What's wrong in nested `\discretionary`-ies?

P.S. Armenian uses another sign for hyphenation (a slightly curved **֊**, not **-**), so I need to use `\discretionary` anyway.

Comment: Redefining `\hyphenchar` will not help. When the word is hyphenated, **ը** reappears in **դըգ** syllable, regardless of whether it is after or before the hyphenation sign, but when it is not, that **ը** is not written. Just redefining will not control **ը**.

Comment: Yes I was just commenting on your PS that said you needed to use \discretionary as you were not using the ascii hyphen but that shouldn't be the case. (you might need it for other reasons of course). But to your main question oh I see you want something like  abc-Nnq-xyz except that if there is no break at all then it is abcnqxyz   with no N,at all, hmmm luatex might be easier than xetex here

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen nested `\discretionary`ies are not supported in TeX but as a workaround you can use that in most documents every line will have more than five characters, therefore it is unlikely that both hyphenation opportunities are taken. So usually you can archive your goal with

```
յան\h{֊}{դը}{դ}\h{ըգ֊}{}{գ}նել
```

Of course this technically allows the (wrong) hyphenation

```
յան֊
դըըգ֊
նել
```

but under normal linelengths this is unlikely to be chosen because "դըըգ֊" is far from filling a line.

If you don't want to make such a compromise, you need **LuaTeX**. While LuaTeX doesn't support nested discretionaries in general either, it does support one special case which should be applicable here: Use

```
\newcommand\weirddisc[6]{%
  \discretionary{#1}{#2}{#3}\discretionary{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \directlua{
    local last = tex.nest.top.tail
    last.subtype = 5
    last.prev.subtype = 4
  }}
...
յան\weirddisc{֊}{դըգ}{դգ}{դըգ֊}{}{դըգ-}նել
```

Here

```
\weirddisc{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
```

represents the "nested discretionaries"

```
\h{1}{\h{4}{5}{2}}{\h{6}{5}{3}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!